# Region monitoring

Tags: ios, ios5, regions

can anyone tell me how accurate the iOS5 region monitoring function can be. i.e. can it use my GPS location to monitor when I enter a region.

Also what is the max number of regions I could configure at any given time.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

So so accurate for ios 5: should be from 1 to 150 m, ios 6: 1 to 400m

Max number of regions 20 per application.

The notifications are NOT instant though, and there are other things like cushion region and such.

According to apple:

> In iOS 6, regions with a radius between 1 and 400 meters work better
>   on iPhone 4S or later devices. (In iOS 5, regions with a radius
>   between 1 and 150 meters work better on iPhone 4S and later devices.)
>   On these devices, an app can expect to receive the appropriate region
>   entered or region exited notification within 3 to 5 minutes on
>   average, if not sooner.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion: